# Error: The user specified as a definer ('Admin'@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

> Error de SQL (1449): The user specified as a definer ('Admin'@'%') does not exist

I have this error when I'm trying to update a table. I don't know what I must do, because this error only happens with one table, but I don't want to damage other tables and the database.

I've searched how to fix it and I've executed this query:

> **Transact-SQL:**  *show procedure status*

But it doesn't show me the definer of my database.

What do I have to do without damaging the database?

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, I executed this query and it worked. We need change the word 'someuser' for 'Admin' in my case.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'complex-password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```